# A question on representation of commutative groups

Tags: representation-theory

I am recently reading Naimark and Stern's book "Theory of Group Representations". On page 37, an exercise is to show that a finite dimensional representation of a finite commutative group is a direct sum of one-dimensional representations. I know that such representation has at least one 1-dimentional representation, but don't have a clue how to prove this statement. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that every representation is a direct sum of irreducibles? If so, then the problem reduces to showing that every irreducible representation of a finite abelian group is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think every representation is a direct sum of irreducible representations.

Comment: Some mild hypotheses are necessary: the ground field needs to have the property that its characteristic does not divide the order of the group. This is Maschke's theorem, also mentioned in Joel's answer.

Comment: Thanks. It's only for finite groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use induction on the dimension (and Maschke's theorem).

If $\dim V = 1$, it's over. If not, then $V$ is not irreducible (for an abelian group, only one-dimensional representations are), so there's a sub-representation, say $U \subset V$. Then because of [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem), $U$ admits an invariant direct complement $W$. So you've written

$$V = W \oplus U$$

where both $W$ and $U$ are sub-representation of lower dimension, which enables you to use induction and conclude.

To prove that irreducible representations of an abelian group are one-dimensional, use Schur's Lemma : let $G$ be an abelian group, and $(\pi, V)$ be an irreducible representation of $G$. Let $g \in G$, you can check (using commutativity) that $\pi(g) : V \to V$ is an intertwining from $(\pi, V)$ to itself. So from Schur's lemma, there exists $\lambda_g$ such that $g.v = \lambda_g v$ for all $v \in V$. If $v \in V$ is non-zero, the linear span of $v$ is one-dimensional and stable under the action of $G$, so it's $V$ (from irreducibility of $V$), and $\dim V = 1$.